# Objective-C for Dummies: How to change the region without invoking mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location

so I have my self a conundrum. I'm changing the region of an MKMapView in code, which works, however it invokes the `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated` which cancels my check if the user is the one actually moving the map. So, I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to manually set region in code while also checking if the user changes it (it's also 2:30 AM and my brain isn't really cooperating...). Anyway, here's my code:

```
- (void)displayMyLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    if (!userChangedRegion) {
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        MKCoordinateRegion region;

        span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

        region.center = location.coordinate;
        region.span = span;

        [map setRegion:region];
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    userChangedRegion = YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to skip setting `userChangedRegion` when *you* change the region, you could use a second variable `programChangedRegion` to track whether you are currently setting the region.

For example:

```
        programChangedRegion = YES;
        [map setRegion:region];
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (programChangedRegion == YES) {
        programChangedRegion = NO;
    } else {
        userChangedRegion = YES;
    }
}
```